# java Makefile doesn't work

Tags: java, makefile

Here the tree of my java project :

- src

  - package_name
- doc
- bin
- Makefile

.java files are in src/package_name directory and my Makefile doesn't works :

```
JC=javac
SRC=src/package_name
JAVA_SRCS=$(wildcard src/package_name/*.java)
JAVA_CLASSES=$(subst src/package_name/,bin/,$(JAVA_SRCS:.java=.class))


bin/%.class: $(SRC)/%.java
    $(JC) -classpath bin/ -d bin/ $<


class: $(JAVA_CLASSES)
```

That's okay for basic file compilation but the classpath doesn't works :(

Can you help me please ?

Comment: My advice is not to use makefiles for java. Use ant or what your IDE provides.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer use vi than an IDE

Comment: Your choice. But then better use ant or maven.

Answer (score 1):

> That's okay for basic file compilation but the classpath doesn't work ...

You are probably not doing it properly.  Unfortunately, we can't tell what you are actually doing because your example rule is simply setting the classpath to the "./bin" directory.

Perhaps you are expecting `javac` to respect both `-classpath` and the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.  It won't.  If you provide a `-classpath` argument, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is ignored.

---

But a better solution it to switch to Ant or Maven for doing your builds.  They both understand all about Java and its tool chain ... and lots more.